# Rasberry PI 3 debian /sys/class/gpio/export error

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, gpio

I've a problem
When I run on my raspberry pi 3 (debian10)

`echo 17 > /sys/class/gpio/export`

I get error

`-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument`

Help me please

Answer (score 0):

run
`CONFIG_DEVMEM_STRICT=y`

add
`iomem=relaxed` to `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt`

and reboot solved this problem

Comment: How can `CONFIG_DEVMEM_STRICT=y` have any effect ? After reboot, it's gone.

Comment: Just setting `CONFIG_DEVMEM_STRICT` to `y` wouldn't do very much, would it?